# How do I change contact numbers to contact names?

Tags: android, contacts, names, inbox

**Is there a way to display the contact names instead of the contact numbers?**

This method returns the phone numbers within an inbox, but I need the names instead:

**UPDATE: code changed from the original.**

**NOTE: I'm trying to change the contact numbers to display their corresponding contact names in the INBOX. Im not trying to get a list of all available contacts names.**

```
public ArrayList<String> fetchInboxNumbers() {

    ArrayList<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
            new String[] { "_id", "address", "date", "body" }, null, null,                                                              
            null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String address = cursor.getString(1); // Displays phone number

        sms.add(address);
    }
    return sms;
} // END FETCHINBOX
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to display the contact names instead of the contact
>   numbers?

Following Snippet will help you.

```
        String whereName = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
        String[] whereNameParams = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
        Cursor nameCur = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, whereName, whereNameParams, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
        while (nameCur.moveToNext()) {
            String given = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
            String family = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
            String display = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
        nameCur.close();
```

Comment: I realized I made a mistake in the code I posted earlier. This is the version I'm working with. I'm reading the numbers in my sms inbox, but its showing phone numbers. Do you know how to apply your above code to that?

Answer (score 0):

I will like to add to @Vipul Shah answer.

wouldnt be better to add a projection with only the columns that you need to retreive?

```
new String [] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, 
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME }
```

Regards